# Como guardar qual item do Navigation Drawe selecionei

Tags: java, android

Boa madrugada galera, estou desenvolvendo um app e coloquei um navigation drawer nele bem básico, e gostaria de saber como faço pra "guardar" qual item está selecionado. E assim sempre que o app abrir, irá abrir no fragment que coloquei nesse item do menu (navigation drawer)

Ex para melhor compreensão:

Meu app é de horóscopo e meu menu contém todos os signos, se eu selecionei "libra" toda vez que meu app abrir, abrirá no fragment libra.

Agradeço desde já

Comment: tentar salvar essa informação em um banco de dados basico e alterar o setcontentview colocando o conteudo igual a variavel do banco de dados

Answer (score 0):

Eu faço algo bem pouco parecido com o que você procura, no meu caso é o login automático.

Apos o usuário fazer login no meu app eu salvo o usuário e a senha e na próxima vez que ele entrar eu verifico se o arquivo existe e faço a leitura dos dados e faço o login automático, caso dê tudo certo, o user é direcionado para a tela principal, caso contrário vai para a tela de login.

No seu caso, você pode salvar um arquivo de configuração contendo o item selecionado, e quando o app iniciar você vai neste arquivo e verifica qual foi o item selecionado. E quando o usuário fizer uma nova seleção, você altera o arquivo.

Comment: Estudarei isso, pois estou iniciando em desenvolvimento android e não sei muitas coisas, se puder dar uma dica de por onde começar agradeço

Answer (score 0):

Coloque uma variavel que quando vc clica em tal item ele pega tal valor, ex: clicou no item 1 a variavel seta 1, aí você faz com que o app salve esse dado em localstorage, quando ele abrir novamente carregue o dado e então faça oque você quer.

Answer (score 0):

Uma opção é utilizar as [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#java) do Android. É um mecanismo para armazenar `key-values`. Na documentação tem alguns exemplos de como utilizar esta classe.

Quando o usuário clicar em um item da gaveta você poderia guardar em uma chave qual o nome do signo que ele acessou:

```
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("nome_do_arquivo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("ultimo_signo", "nome_do_signo_clicado");
editor.commit();
```

E quando ele abrir o app novamente, você pode recuperar este signo e fazer algo com essa informação:

```
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("nome_do_arquivo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String ultimoSigno = sharedPref.getString("ultimo_signo", "valor_padrao_caso_nao_exista_um_signo_ainda");
```